# Converting cURL POST to Perl POST

Tags: linux, perl

I'm having issues converting a cURL request to Perl. FWIW, using v5.10.1 on IBM AIX 7.1.

in cURL:

```
curl -s -u $USER:$PWD --data '@mft.json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST $EVENT_URL
```

in Perl:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(); 


my $user = "aaa";
my $pwd = "bbb";
my $port = 7090;
my $domain = "my.site.com";
my $url = "http://".$domain.":".$port;
my $event_url = $url."/mftapp/rest/v1/events";
my $file = "mft.json";

$ua->credentials($domain.":".$port, 'default', $user, $pwd);

my $response = $ua->post($event_url, Content_Type => 'form-data', Content => [file => $file]
);

my $content = $response->as_string();

print ($content);
```

Depending on the value of `Content_Type`, I get different results:

- Content_Type = "application/json", Bad Request 400
- Content_Type = "form-data", Unsupported Media Type 415
- Content_Type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", Unsupported Media Type 415

Using these methods in order to add headers breaks my code:

```
$ua->default_header('Content-Type' => 'application/json')
```

Can't locate object method "default_header" via package "LWP::UserAgent" at request.pl line 20.

Comment: Which version of LWP::UserAgent is this?

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, post an answer. Don't edit your question.

Comment: @melpomene well, the answer came from hobbs (misunderstanding of the post method) and wanted to paste the piece of code that I actually used.

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus I'd say that counts as an answer.

Comment: Also see https://corion.net/curl2lwp.psgi on how to convert from Curl to LWP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Content => [file => $file]` doesn't do what you think it does. You're just sending garbage to the server, which is why it says "Bad Request" even when you tell it that the body is JSON (which is the correct choice).

I would recommend adding `use Path::Tiny;` and using

```
$ua->post($event_url,
    Content_Type => 'application/json',
    Content => path($file)->slurp_utf8,
);
```

which will actually read and send the contents of `$file`.

Comment: use Path::Tiny; gives Can't locate Path/Tiny.pm in @INC. The same with use File::Slurp; I ended up using a basic file read and I'm now getting an HTTP 200.

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus Well, yes. You're going to have to install Path::Tiny, just like LWP::UserAgent (neither module comes with perl).

Comment: @melpomene I just went with a basic file read (see edit). Not my server in this case and I'm unsure if I have sufficient permissions to install it.

Comment: @hobbs thanks for pointing me in the right direction, that is, to read the file in and posting that instead.